# 2 компьютера подключены к одному роутеру , на одном интернет 4мбит на втором 0.5мбит

Tags: сеть, администрирование, роутер, вирусы

Есть 2 компьютера подключены к одному роутеру , на одном интернет 4мбит на втором 0.5мбит

Перезагружал роутер , перезагружал пк , проходился антивирусом ,обновил драйвера, искал процессы в диспетчере, менял порты в роутере , делал сброс параметров сети, менял кабели на ПК, проверил ip и мак адресы на 2-х ПК они разные. Суть одна в независимости от того какой порт и какой кабель , один конкретный ПК работает с медленным интернетом

Так же заметил что на том ПК где плохой интернет пинг стабильно 60 , это очень плохой пинг для этого провайдера + подключал wifi к пк и подключился к роутеру скорость и пинг точно такой же. Хотя на других устройствах которые подключены к wifi этого роутера скорость в разы лучше и пинг тоже

Comment: Может, банально в настройках роутера стоит ограничение скорости для этого конкретного компьютера?

Comment: Ну его точно никто не ставил, по крайне мере)

Comment: Точно нет ограничений  , иногда скорость у него бывало и до 6 доходила , но это был конкретный не большой период

Comment: А интернет какой? Может, какие-то ограничения со стороны интернет-провайдера, которые один компьютер обходит хитрыми способами, а другой не обходит?

Comment: Править MTU. Кривое.

Comment: Провайдер сказал нет , что он вообще не имеет отношения к моему пк он дает только 1 сигнал на роутер и все